# Why does the optirun command shut down my computer?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on the Ivy Bridge Sony Vaio S. I installed bumblebee for nvidia-optimus support. Everything seemed to install fine, but if I use a command like:
    optirun firefox
my computer just shuts down. No proper shutdown sequence or anything, just boom. down.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See the Bumblebee trouble shooting guide:

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting

If you still have problems, you will need to file a bug report:

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/new